# Выбрать из таблицы один параметр по двум колонкам

Tags: php, medoo

Использую библиотеку Medoo, нужно получить запись из таблицы, где user_one = (мой id) или где user_two = (мой id), но выборка происходит только значению user_one

```
$get = self::select('*', ['OR' =>['user_one' => $myid]], ['OR' => ['user_two' =>$myid] ]);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это решить?

Код функции

```
public static function allConversation()
{
    $myid = account::getUsrByName($_SESSION['login'])[0]['id'];
    $get = self::select('*', ['OR' =>['user_one' => $myid]], ['OR' => ['user_two' =>$myid] ]);
    if ($get !== null && is_array($get)) {
        // что то делается
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
$get = self::select('conversation','*', ['OR' => ['user_one' => $myid, 'user_two' => $myid]
]);
//Не проверял
```

Answer (score 0):

Решила таким образом

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `conversation` WHERE (user_one='$myid') OR (user_two='$myid')";
    $get = self::query($query)->fetchAll();
```